# To check boundedness of Sequence of partial sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

which one of the following statements is true for the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{(2n)!}{n^{2n}}$ ?

A)The series converges conditionally but not absolutely

B)The series converges absolutely

C)The sequence of partial sums of the series is bounded but not convergent

D)The sequence of partial sums of the series is unbounded.

Leibniz Test for alternating series: Given series is of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n}{a_n}$

Since $a_{n+1}-{a_n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n^{2n}}\left[\frac{{n^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)}{2n+2}}{n^2{(n+1)^{2n+2}}}-1\right] \lt{0}$$ {\forall{n}}$

hence (i)$a_n\to0 $ $as n\to\infty$ (ii) $a_n$ is decreasing.Hence by Leibniz Theorem given series is convergent.

Is there any other way to check this?

Ratio Test:consider $lim_{x \to 0}\vert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\vert=lim_{x \to 0}\frac{{(2n+2)!} {n^{2n}}}{{(n+1)^{2n+2}} {(2n)!}}=lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)}=4 \gt{1}$ Hence divergent.

please tell me what is wrong in my calculations?

Comment: Have you heard of alternating series?

Comment: Re-check your calculations in the ratio test.

Comment: yes it is alternating series and using Leibniz theorem for alternating series  I got convergent and for convergent series sequence of partial sum is always bounded. But using Ratio Test I am getting divergent? Calculations are shown above.